# How to extract creation date and modification date in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, date

How to extract creation date and modification date?

```
$CameraFolder = "H:\CameraTemp" 
$CameraItems = $CameraFolder.GetFolder.Items()

foreach ($OggettoFile in ($CameraItems | Sort-Object -Property Name) ){

 echo "$($OggettoFile.Name) - $($OggettoFile.type) - $($OggettoFile.ExtendedProperty("size")) - $($OggettoFile.ExtendedProperty("ModifyDate")) <- Debug"

 # foreach ($ep in $OggettoFile.ExtendedProperties) {
 #     echo $ep.value # outup is null :..(
 # }
 # this example No Work!!!
}
```

Output of this script

```
> file1.jpg - File MP4 - 1653511 -  <- Debug
> file2.jpg - File MP4 - 1655538 -  <- Debug
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -Property Name,LastWriteTime,CreationTime`

Comment: your suggestion in my case, output -> file1.jpg  null null

Comment: [1] there is no `.GetFolder` method or property on a string. [2] there is no `.ExtendedProperty` property on `fileinfo` items. ///// so ... **_how on earth are you getting anything at all from that code?_** [*grin*]

Comment: thank you @Olaf , your suggestion made me think, I found alternative solution, thank you again.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. ;-)  ... never stop thinking!! :-D

Answer (score 2):

Lets make this more powershell like.

```
Get-ChildItem "H:\CameraTemp" | Sort-Object -Property Name | Foreach-Object{
    "$($_.Name) - $($_.Extension) - $($_.Length) - $($_.CreationTime) - $($_.LastWriteTime)"
}
```

In powershell we LOVE piping aka `|` !
It takes the Response from the last command and moves it to the next command. Then powershell creates a variable for it `$_`

Output will look like

```
phpversion.php - .php - 15 - 04/21/2020 09:56:52 - 04/21/2020 09:56:53
services.htm - .htm - 12881 - 04/21/2020 09:50:07 - 04/21/2020 09:55:07
```

Comment: You don't need a loop for that. Just use a `Select-Object`.

Comment: Olaf I would agree with you BUT he wanted a string output like `stuff - stuff - stuff`

Comment: Where do you know that?  ;-)  Do you expect the code he posted was written by himself?

Comment: I take it off his output was a echo " Stuff - Stuff - Stuff". I am just matching his exact same output

Comment: Any reference, especially regex, `$_`?

Comment: @CloudCho There is no Regex needed. The variable $_ is a reserved variable in Powershell. it represents the item in the pipe. So instead of doing `Foreach($i in $Array){ Write-Host $i }` i can do `$Array | ForEach-Object{ Write-Host $_ }`